# create multiple thread for read and write with PyQt5

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I write a code with PyQt5 for send and receive data via serial port. when a button pressed, data sends without any problem. in receive, data packet length is different in every time and time between any send is random. I create a thread for read serial port buffer in while loop and if data was received, then put that in a global queue. in other thread , queue will be checked and if it is not empty, some process will be done on data. 
but when I test program and send data to application , the bellow error display and application crash. 
the error:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
>     (Parent is QTextDocument(0x1d1166f7620), parent's thread is QThread(0x1d116712ff0), current thread is 
>     QThread(0x1d1166f7560)

here is the main part of code:

> ```
> import sys
> from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
> import errordialog as D1 
> import serial 
> import serial.tools.list_ports 
> import threading
> import queue
>
>
> class Ui_Form(threading.Thread):
> def __init__(self):
>     threading.Thread.__init__(self)
>
> def setupUi(self, Form):
>
>     self.q = queue.Queue()
>     .
>     .
>     .
>
> def open_port(self):
>
>     if self.comboBoxPORT.count()==0:
>         dialog.exec_()
>     else:
>         self.ser.port = self.comboBoxPORT.currentText()
>         b=int(self.lineEditBaudrate.text())
>         if b==0:
>             self.ser.baudrate = 9600
>         else:
>             self.ser.baudrate = int(self.lineEditBaudrate.text())
>
>         try:
>             self.ser.open()
>             self.pushButtonClose.setEnabled(True)
>             self.pushButtonOpen.setEnabled(False)
>             self.pushButtonOpen.setStyleSheet("background-color: lime")
>             self.pushButtonSend.setEnabled(True)
>             self.comboBoxPORT.setEnabled(False)
>             self.lineEditBaudrate.setEnabled(False)
>             self.textEditReceived.setReadOnly(False)
>             g=threading.Thread(target=ui.read_data)
>             e=threading.Thread(target=ui.printData)
>             g.start()
>             e.start()                
>         except:
>             dialog.exec_()
>
> def read_data(self):
>     while True:
>         t = self.ser.read().decode()
>         if t:            
>             self.q.put(t)
>
> def printData(self):
>     while True:
>         while not self.q.empty():
>             print(self.q.get())
>             self.textEditReceived.setText(self.q.get())
>
> def close_port(self):
>     try:
>         self.ser.close()
>         self.pushButtonClose.setEnabled(False)
>         self.pushButtonOpen.setEnabled(True)
>         self.pushButtonOpen.setStyleSheet("background-color: azure")
>         self.pushButtonSend.setEnabled(False)
>         self.comboBoxPORT.setEnabled(True)
>         self.lineEditBaudrate.setEnabled(True)
>     except:
>         dialog.exec_()
>
> def send(self):
>     self.ser.write(str.encode(self.textEditSent.toPlainText()))
>
>  if __name__ == "__main__":
>      import sys
>      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
>      Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
>      ui = Ui_Form()
>      ui.setupUi(Form)
>      Form.show()
> ##============= add error dialog
>     d1 = D1.Ui_DialogError()
>     dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
>     d1.setupUi(dialog)
> ##---======================----------
>     ui.pushButtonOpen.clicked.connect(lambda : ui.open_port())
>     d1.pushButtonCanceError.clicked.connect(lambda: dialog.close())
>     ui.pushButtonExit.clicked.connect(lambda: Form.close())
>     ui.pushButtonClose.clicked.connect(lambda: ui.close_port())
>     ui.pushButtonSend.clicked.connect(lambda: ui.send())
> ##=============-----------------
> ##----------====================
>
>     sys.exit(app.exec_())
> ```

Comment: use QSerialPort

Comment: Also, please be more careful when formatting code in your questions. Read more about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).